# Airflow kubernetesPorOperator example fails to run

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

Trying to run sample kubernetesPodOperator retrieves:

> [2020-05-25 20:00:40,475] {{**init**.py:51}} INFO - Using executor
>   LocalExecutor
>   [2020-05-25 20:00:40,475] {{dagbag.py:396}} INFO - Filling up the
>   DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags/kubernetes_example.py
>   │ │ Traceback (most recent call last):
>   │ │   File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 37, in 
>   │ │     args.func(args)
>   │ │   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line
>   75, in wrapper
>   │ │     return f(*args, **kwargs)
>   │ │   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 523,
>   in run
>   │ │     dag = get_dag(args)
>   │ │   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 149,
>   in get_dag
>   │ │     'parse.'.format(args.dag_id))
>   │ │ airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: dag_id could not be found:
>   kubernetes_example. Either the dag did not exist or it failed to
>   parse.

This is the code I am using:

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago



default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': days_ago(1),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=60)
}

dag = DAG(
    'kubernetes_example', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=60))


start = DummyOperator(task_id='run_this_first', dag=dag)

passing = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace='airflow',
                          image="python:3.6.10",
                          cmds=["Python","-c"],
                          arguments=["print('hello world')"],
                          labels={"foo": "bar"},
                          name="passing-test",
                          task_id="passing-task",
                          env_vars={'EXAMPLE_VAR': '/example/value'},
                          in_cluster=True,
                          get_logs=True,
                          dag=dag
                          )

failing = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace='airflow',
                          image="ubuntu:18.04",
                          cmds=["Python","-c"],
                          arguments=["print('hello world')"],
                          labels={"foo": "bar"},
                          name="fail",
                          task_id="failing-task",
                          get_logs=True,
                          dag=dag
                          )

passing.set_upstream(start)
failing.set_upstream(start)
```

I just took it from sample executor.
Did someone stumble upon this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: can you post your code? I am pretty sure you DAG definition is wrong, missing the `dag_id`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, added the DAG

Comment: Thanks, check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a name (the `dag_id` for your dag).

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='kubernetes_example', 
    default_args=default_args, 
    schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=60)
)
```

Also your task_id should have `_` not `-` and be: `task_id="failing_task"`

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, but its not the problem, I changed the DAG according your comment and it did not solve the issue. BTW you can see in the tutorial (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/tutorial.html) that it not a must. tried anyway and it didnt work out for me. still appreciate the help

Comment: sorry, my bad, also my suggestion for the task_id was not necessary (I am just sticking to much to our internal guidelines). But your code on my machine generates the dag correctly, I wonder if your problem in not just an old version of Airflow on your machine

Comment: I am using the latest 1.10.10 version. may be my deployment has flows.. are using helm chart? could you please share your deployment/chart? (only if possible). Thanks anyway mucio!

Comment: I am using an internal multi-tenant Airflow. I am also wondering if the dag your Airflow is trying to load is the actual file you are modifying or an older copy

Comment: The thing that realy drives me crazy is it outputs:
``` INFO - Using executor LocalExecutor``` . Tried changing env var, but it didnt work, may be you have an idea?